# Node / Grunt - use external node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, module, gruntjs

If I have my project in the following folder:

d:\sites\my-project

Which contains the gruntfile.js and package.json

Is there a way I can tell it to install and use dependencies from the following folder:

d:\modules\node_modules

Thanks.

Comment: To help give a better answer why don't you want your node_modules in your project folder?

Comment: @Anthony I have a similar issue. The reason I don't have the node_modules in my project folder is that I don't think is smart to have a copy of the node_modules in EVERY project folder. If I use a JS library I set up a central location for it and include all the versions in it, so if I need to point to any of those I use the localserver's absolute path `<script src="/scripts/library/version/library.js"></script>`. It would be very nice to use something like that in the Gruntfile and not be forced to create a copy of the modules in every folder, I believe is unnecessary. Just my two cents.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue